# Joomla Timezone errors

Tags: php, joomla

Recentlly updated PHP now Im getting these errors when visiting the index.php page.

```
DateTimeZone::__construct() [datetimezone.--construct]: Unknown or bad timezone (0)

Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   JApplicationCms->execute()  /home/user123/public_html/index.php:45
2   JApplicationSite->render()  /home/user123/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:258
3   JApplicationCms->render()   /home/user123/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php:745
4   JDocumentHTML->render() /home/user123/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php:1059
5   JDocumentHTML->_renderTemplate()    /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:477
6   JDocumentHTML->getBuffer()  /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:697
7   JDocumentRendererModules->render()  /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php:411
8   JDocumentRendererModule->render()   /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/modules.php:43
9   JModuleHelper::renderModule()   /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/module.php:103
10  include()   /home/user123/public_html/libraries/cms/module/helper.php:190
11  NSP_GK4_Helper->getDatas()  /home/user123/public_html/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/mod_news_pro_gk4.php:28
12  NSP_GK4_K2_Source->getArticles()    /home/user123/public_html/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/helper.php:302
13  JFactory::getDate() /home/user123/public_html/modules/mod_news_pro_gk4/gk_classes/gk.source.k2.php:128
14  JDate->__construct()    /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/factory.php:530
15  DateTimeZone->__construct() /home/user123/public_html/libraries/joomla/date/date.php:97
```

I have tried, clearing session table, changing time zone in php.ini, commenting out timezone in php.ini, clearing param column in *_users

Any idea?

Comment: It might be useful to tell us which versions of PHP you upgraded from and to, and also what version of Joomla you're running.

Comment: Sorry, running PHP 5.3 - Joomla 3.4.8